# Dynamically changing fillColor variables in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, polygon, layers, style, color-ramp

When I want to style a polygon using a property the traditional way is to assign a function that returns a style object. Within that object you assign the `fillColor` property to a `getColor` function

`fillColor: getColor (feature.properties.population)`

Is this the only way?
What if I want to style layers by dynamically changing the fill variable in a case where a drop-down has 100 feature properties?

Answer (score 0):

One way of dynamically styling vector layer would be to have some global variable and then use it within style function to select desired style. Upon global variable change, `.setStyle` vector layer method has to be used to update style.

This could look then something like this:

```
var selectedPropertyNo = 0;

function style(feature) {
  var fillColor;
  if (selectedPropertyNo == 1)
    fillColor = getDensityColor(feature.properties.density);
  else {
    fillColor = getIncomeColor(feature.properties.income);
  }
  return {
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    fillColor: fillColor
  };
}

function changeLayerStyle(propertyNo) {
  selectedPropertyNo = propertyNo;
  vectorLayer.setStyle(style);
}
```